# How to control speed and direction of video playback with an external signal

Tags: python, video, synchronization, video-processing

For a project idea I am working on I'm looking for (ideally) existing software or some advice on how to achieve the desired function.

The following example isn't actually what I want to build, but it's the simplest explanation of the concept:

Imagine an arcade machine-like situation, where you have a cabinet that contains a video display. Attached to the front of the cabinet is a hand crank. The hand crank drives an encoder of the signal, which is read by a microcontroller, which then sends some form of clock/control signal to the video player software.

- If the hand crank is at rest, the display shows a still frame from a video file. 
   Let's call this frame X.
- One clockwise turn of the hand crank advances to frame X+1, whereas one anticlockwise turn would result in frame X-1 being shown.
- Steadily turning the crank in a clockwise direction at a rate of 30 turns per second plays the video forward at 30 fps.
- Steadily turning the crank in an anticlockwise direction at a rate of 15 turns per second plays the video in reverse at 15 fps.
- Achievable frame rates should be between 0 and around 60.

The whole idea is quite like synching video to an external timecode signal, only that I need forward and reverse playback and variable speed.

It needs to run fullscreen and should ideally be platform independent.

My instinct tells me that Python would be a good candidate, but I don't know Python nearly well enough to judge, and might very well be wrong.

**Question:**
Does anybody know of an existing solution, or has suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: @wpunkts I added the `video-processing` tag since I suspect you will have to edit metadata or even extract frame bytes from the video file. **(1)** You need to ask a real **programming** question. All good about hand cranks but actually what is your _"external signal"_ here? Are you asking how can I use the keyboard to control a video's speed and direction?

Comment: @wpunkts **(2)** Sorry but this task might be too advanced if you have to ask like this. Why **no details** about resolution or length? Maybe a solution is to extract each frame as a picture then do a slideshow. **No details** about the format? Maybe if it was MP4 you could use an **edit list** to re-order the frames to display in reverse. **No details** about why you think this can be done (_eg:_ Have you ever played a video from bytes before? Because that's how you'd play with edited speed/direction settings within the video's bytes).

Comment: @wpunkts final noise... **(3)** If this was my problem, I would just make a web page. That would solve the _"platform independent"_ part. Also in HTML/Javascript you can control video speed with `.playbackRate` setting. I would then just have two copies loaded (one put in reverse order with a video editor) and simply change visibility of the either forwards/backwards video objects. That is the minimum way without getting technically deep. Maybe try the two videos idea in Python.